# python cProfile giving 'int' object is not callable error

Tags: python, profiler, cprofile

Following script runs great:

```
$ python myscript.py
```

When I try to profile my code using cProfile like:

```
$ python -m cProfile -s time myscript.py
```

or

```
$ python -m cProfile myscript.py
```

I get following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/runpy.py", line 121, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/runpy.py", line 34, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/cProfile.py", line 190, in <module>
    main()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/cProfile.py", line 183, in main
    run('execfile(%r)' % (sys.argv[0],), options.outfile, options.sort)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/cProfile.py", line 36, in run
    result = prof.print_stats(sort)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/cProfile.py", line 81, in print_stats
    pstats.Stats(self).strip_dirs().sort_stats(sort).print_stats()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/pstats.py", line 92, in __init__
    self.init(arg)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/pstats.py", line 106, in init
    self.load_stats(arg)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/pstats.py", line 130, in load_stats
    arg.create_stats()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/cProfile.py", line 92, in create_stats
    self.snapshot_stats()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/cProfile.py", line 106, in snapshot_stats
    callersdicts[id(entry.code)] = callers
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

My script runs successfully in both the cases except that it chokes cProfile in latter case.   I know it has to be something really petty, just cant nail it.

Please help me resolve. Thanks

Comment: I tried googling, closest link I could get is http://infix.se/2009/09/03/profile-this It states same error, but doesnt mention any solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have an integer variable named `id` that is masking the built-in function [`id`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#id). That is messing up `cProfile`.

Rename your `id` variable and `cProfile` should work fine.

Comment: Absolutely, its `id` that was messing up things. My bad, I realise. Thanks again

Comment: @jerrymouse It happens to everyone. `id` is even used in the standard library as a name because it's so convenient. Ignore the downvoters, this was a perfectly fine question.